# Spin polarization, ferromagnetism, and size of energy gap

Tags: electronic-band-theory, ferromagnetism, spin-statistics

I thought large band gap (larger than relevant spin-spin interaction energy scale) necessarily means there is no spin-polarization (ie, not ferromagnetic). I thought the reason is that {only when hypothetical-no-spin-band-gap (from non-spin-polarized dft calculation, for instance) is small, it is possible for the spin-spin energy save to be larger than the energy cost of going into the hypothetical-no-spin-conduction-band in order to create unpaired elections. When the band gap is too large, electron just want to be in the valance band and to be all paired-up, which means not ferromagnetic.

However, I see that Indium oxide is "a transparent, conducting ferromagnetic semiconductor" with band gap "3.75 eV (direct) or 2.61 eV (indirect)", so I guess my previous thought must be wrong. What's wrong with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Spin-spin interaction is not responsible for ferromagnetism. This is a common missconception. It is rather a question of exchange energy, i.e. kinetic energy on a single particle level. So there is unfortunately no easy rule involving the size of the bandgap and spin-spin energy scale.

Comment: "It is rather a question of exchange energy" do you mean that the paired spins occupying the same spatial orbital, repel each other more through electrostatic interaction? (Compared to same spin electron occupying different spatial orbital). What is the typical energy scale of such effect? More specifically, if a spin unpolarized dft calculation gives a certain band gap. How large does the band gap needs to be so we can pretty confidently say that it's not going to be spin polarized?